# database is not accepting new entries - mongodb with mongoose and express.js

Tags: node.js, express

This may not be right area, but I set up the blobs app, used by Kendrick Coleman in his youtube

Making the Switch Ruby on Rails to Node js + Express by Kendrick Coleman at #fsotconf15

I have built the database and also the app but when i seek to add details, it says

There was a problem adding the information to the database.

Here is the extract of the code in the js file //POST a new blob .post(function(req, res) { // Get values from POST request. These can be done through forms or REST calls. These rely on the "name" attributes for forms var name = req.body.name; var badge = req.body.badge; var dob = req.body.dob; var company = req.body.company; var isloved = req.body.isloved; //call the create function for our database mongoose.model('Blob').create({ name : name, badge : badge, dob : dob, isloved : isloved }, function (err, blob) { if (err) { res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database."); } else { //Blob has been created console.log('POST creating new blob: ' + blob); res.format({ //HTML response will set the location and redirect back to the home page. You could also create a 'success' page if that's your thing html: function(){ // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /adduser res.location("blobs"); // And forward to success page res.redirect("/blobs"); }, //JSON response will show the newly created blob json: function(){ res.json(blob); } }); } }) });

Comment: Can you make is beautify. I can't understand the code you have shown here. Please insert the code sample.

Comment: maybe best to show what happens to the server when I make a call